# What theme does Runnable Use for their Ace Editor Implementation

Tags: ace-editor

It looks as though runnable.com uses ace code editor. What is the purple theme they use?

http://runnable.com/UmGTLn0iIYljAAEu/codemirror-example-change-theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears they are using custom theme `runnable_dark`. Try running `ace.define.modules["ace/theme/runnable_dark"].cssText` in devtools to see it's css.

Comment: I eventually found that as well in their JavaScript by viewing the source code of the page. Any idea how to get their ACE editor js file for the theme? I tried doing several different searches for it, but wasn't successful. I guess it would be something like theme_runnable_dark.js

Comment: It's merged with other files search for runnable_dark in devtools, or use value of cssText

Comment: Thanks a user. I'm making a browser based IDE, and I'd love to have a theme similar to the one they use.